# Xcode complains: "LLDB provided no error string."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos, xcode12

I get this error when deploying my watchOS App to my Apple Watch. It is impossible to deploy it successfully:

> "LLDB Provided No Error String"
> [image]

I tried cleaning the project and restarting all devices but nothing helped.

I am using the latest Xcode 12.5

Comment: Look into any localized string file, it might have problem.

Comment: @iphonic I don't support any other languages thus I don't have a string file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. I have Just unchecked: Target-> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Info -> Debug executable.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer (turning off the debugger) worked for me, but the underlying reason for this seemed to be that I was running incompatible Xcode and Swift versions (13.4 and 5.7, respectively). After installing the Swift 5.6 toolchain and switching to it in my project, it worked fine. You can see a compatibility matrix here for Xcode / Swift here: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/